# Visual Studio SSRS editor zoom option

Tags: reporting-services

I am new to SSRS. I am try to edit an existing report in VS2013. I'd like to be able to zoom in on a given area so that I can have fine control over dragging a column. I cannot find a zoom option.

Alternatively, if there is no zoom option, is there a way to set a column width in a tablix?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Ctrl + "+" will zoom in on the workspace. Alternatively, in the "Report" toolbar just underneath the menu bar (if it's not already visible, go to View->Toolbars->Report) you can change the zoom percentage.

To set the column width manually, select a single cell within the column- not the entire column- and go to the Properties window (or press F4.) You can set the width under the "Size" property.

Also, you can hold Ctrl while resizing with a mouse for finer control that ignores auto-snapping.